# HTML: Remove space between two inputs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4

I saw this pretty from from website.

[image]

I decided to make it using bootstrap 4, and I failed because of the space between two html input elements. It is neither padding nor margin, I have no idea what is it. I tried to remove the space several times but failed.

[image]

The space between two inputs giving me suffer.

This is HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <div class="form__wrapper">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="newsletter" placeholder="Email address"/>
           <input type="submit" class="newsletter__button"/>
      </div>
  </form>
```

This is CSS

```
 .form__wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

form {
    display: block;
}

form input[type='email'], form input[type='text'] {
    cursor: text;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #E1E0E1;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
.form__wrapper input[type='email'] {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the ruleset for the button. Can you add that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gap origins from the space between two inline elements in the source code. that is parsed as a blank space.

However, you don't have to deal with this issue - for this case exactly, Bootstrap provides [Input Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/). Just use the `input-group` class as a wrapper for the two form elements and the `input-group-added` as a wrapper for the button.

You can style the form elements by using a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in your selectors. The Icon can also be achieved by FontAwesome (see Nisarg Shahs good answer for that). Here is an example:

[image]

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

.input-group>.form-control,
.input-group .btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #e3e3e3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.95em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.input-group>.form-control {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" aria-label="Email Address" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">&gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called an [add-on](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#multiple-addons) in Bootstrap 4. Here's an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control" aria-label="Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can combine that with FontAwesome, to get the desired result:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control" aria-label="Dollar amount (with dot and two decimal places)">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has this built in:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control newsletter" placeholder="Email" type="text">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <input class="form-control"t type="submit" class="newsletter__button"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write both of your input tags in the same line. Here I've included the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p64f7nrk/2/). You can see the difference. :)

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="newsletter" placeholder="Email address"/><input type="submit" class="newsletter__button"/>
```